# How to create a new copy of an existing JPanel?

Tags: java

For example i already have a JPanel

```
JPanel p1=new JPanel();
p1.add(component1);p1.add(component2);p1.add(component3);
```

is there a way to create a new JPanel without  adding all the components repeatedly?
e.g "p1Copy.add(button1),etc..."
or is there a way to make this code shorter?

```
JPanel p1=new JPanel();
P1.add(component1);p1.add(component2);p1.add(component3);
JPanel p1Copy=new JPanel();
p1Copy.add(component1);p1Copy.add(component2);p1Cope.add(component3);
```

i tried using `JPanel p1Copy=p1;` but it fails to create a new JPanel.

Comment: ***fails to create a new JPanel*** what happens? What errors do you get?

Comment: @kiner_shah There wouldn't be an error, it would be a reference to the existing `JPanel`.

Comment: I did not get an error, It was like the panel from the First Frame was transferred to the second Frame which I wanted to have the same exact JPanel.